# Найти сумму модулей отрицательных нечетных элементов

Tags: c#

Дан двухмерный массив 5×5. Найти сумму модулей отрицательных нечетных элементов.
Я написал код и столкнулся с такой проблемой, отрицательные числа  между собой должны прибавляться , например : -5 -5 - 4 = -14 . А у меня выходит совсем другая сумма . Либо я чего-то не понимаю , либо у меня код не правильный . Помогите пожалуйста , буду благодарен за любой ответ !
Вот мой код :

```
 int n = 5, m = 5;
            int[,] matrix = new int[n, m];
            int sum = 0;
           
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = rnd.Next(-10, 10);
                    Console.Write($" {matrix[i, j]}  ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Нечетные отрицательные елементы");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    if ((matrix[i, j] < 0) && (matrix[i, j] % 2 != 0))
                    {
                        sum = matrix[i, j];
                        Console.Write($"{sum}");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Write(" Сумма: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    if (matrix[i, j] < 0 && matrix[i, j] % 2 == 1)
                        sum += Math.Abs(matrix[i, j]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{sum} ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда второй цикл заканчивает работу, в памяти в переменной sum остается значение последнего элемента массива, который вывелся на экран. И к этому значению вы прибавляете все остальные элементы.
Таким образом, нужно обнулять переменную Sum перед 3-м циклом либо суммировать нечетные отрицательные элементы в другую переменную.

```
 int n = 5, m = 5;
            int[,] matrix = new int[n, m];
            int sum = 0;
           
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = rnd.Next(-10, 10);
                    Console.Write($" {matrix[i, j]}  ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Нечетные отрицательные елементы");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    if ((matrix[i, j] < 0) && (matrix[i, j] % 2 != 0))
                    {
                        sum = matrix[i, j];
                        Console.Write($"{sum}");
                    }
                }
            }
            sum = 0;
            Console.Write(" Сумма: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    if (matrix[i, j] < 0 && matrix[i, j] % 2 == 1)
                        sum += Math.Abs(matrix[i, j]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{sum} ");
```

> Другие комментарии:
>
> 1. Если размер массива всегда 5х5, то зачем создавать 2 дополнительных переменных, если можно обойтись одной: `int[,] matrix = new int[n, n]` или вообще 0: `int[,] metrix = new int[5,5]`
> 2. Так как все элементы, которые вы ищите, отрицательны, то окончательная сумма будет противоположна модулю суммы отрицательных нечетных чисел, следовательно вы можете не использовать Math, а просто прибавлять число:  `sum += matrix[i, j]`, а в конце умножить `sum *= -1`, чтобы получить модуль - неторицательное число.

Comment: Cпасибо большое !

Comment: @Aligat Пожалуйста